# How to remove function name from the Postgres function result?

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the JSON response from the function response and I'm able to achieve that. But the problem is on every response I'm getting the function name also how to fix this issue?

**Current response**

```
[
    {
        "__find_attractions_return_json": {
            "name": "Conrad Pond",
            "lat": 41.01696,
            "lon": -74.22462
        }
    },
    {
        "__find_attractions_return_json": {
            "name": "Crossway Creek",
            "lat": 40.46122,
            "lon": -74.26292
        }
    },
    .....
    .....
]
```

**Required result**

```
[
    {
            "name": "Conrad Pond",
            "lat": 41.01696,
            "lon": -74.22462
    },
    {
            "name": "Crossway Creek",
            "lat": 40.46122,
            "lon": -74.26292
    },
    .....
    .....
]
```

**POSTGRES function**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.__find_attractions_return_json(point character varying, cty varchar)
    RETURNS SETOF json 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
SELECT 
    json_build_object( 
        'name',  name, 
        'lat', lat, 
        'lon', lon
        )
    FROM places
    WHERE country=cty 
    AND ST_DWithin(geom::geography,ST_GeogFromText(point), 50000, false);
END
$BODY$;
```

I'm calling this function from `NodeJs`.

Any kind of help will much be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c27a6e48471ff7917a0db5efa4362cb8)

```
SELECT
    json_agg(elements -> '__find_attractions_return_json')
FROM 
    mytable,
    json_array_elements(mydata) as elements
```

1. `json_array_elements` expands all array elements into one row each
2. for every row getting the value of your removeable key
3. `json_agg` aggregates these value objects